# problem in using CONCAT if the value is Null in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i used CONCAT to get my tags and topics  but if  the story has no tag or topic then result is empty

```
 WHERE 

    CONCAT( ' ', table_stories.tags, ' ' )
    LIKE CONCAT( '%', table_tags.tid, '%' ) 

    AND

    CONCAT( ' ', table_stories.associated, ' ' )
    LIKE CONCAT( '%', table_topics.topicid, '%' )
```

as you see , everything fine unless we have story that has no tag or associated

i used

```
  table_stories.tags IS NULL OR
```

but problem still exists and cant fetch stories with no tag or associated

how can i fix this

Answer (score 3):

I don't have mysql handy to test but `COALESCE()` is probably the function you are looking for.

This returns the first non-null argument (See [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce))

So

```
CONCAT(' ' , COALESCE(table_stories.associated, ' '), ' ')
```

should do the job

Comment: @Mac. I didn't post full code as I do not have access to mysql to test it. But within your CONCAT methods wrap any columns that could be null with a call to COALESCE(column, ' '). This will ensure that if the value is null you get a space instead.